# Oracle Database Connection via SQLPLUS Oracle Client

Tags: database, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am not able to connect to remote Oracle Database connection via SQL Plus. below are more details.

1. I have installed Oracle Client 10.2
2. I am able to connect to Oracle Database via SQLDeveloper.

   ```
   Problem : Getting ORA:12154 : TNS : COuld not resolve the connect identifer specfied.
   ```

Tries following

1. from SQL PLUS
2. from command promt `sqlplus username/pwd@host:port/servicename`
3. from command promt "sqlplus username/pwd@host:port/servicename"

and many.

Can anyone please tell me detailed steps to get rid of this problem.

Many Thanks

Comment: What's the difference between try 2) and 3) ?

Comment: What connection settings are you using in SQL Developer - are you using a SID and assuming that's the same as the service name? Is the service name you're using listed by `lsnrctl services` on the server?